# Nesting “IF” statements isn’t returning what I want

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I am trying to use `IF` statements which I hope are the correct formula, I want to say if cell `d8="GB"` then do this sum, but if it does leave column blank so this is the formula I had for that:

```
=IF(d8="GB",j8*t7,"")
```

However this isn’t returning what I want, it says `FALSE` or something if `D8` isn’t `GB` and I need to be able to say if `D8` isn't `GB` just leave the space blank. I thought I had it but it says too many arguments?

Comment: It is recommended to check "", which means blank.

Answer (score 0):

In your formula the answer of `""` isn't treated as blank.
A formula must be a number, text, logical (boolean) or error.
There is no value for "empty" or "blank".

This formula should do better :

```
=IF(d8="GB",j8*t7,TRIM(" "))
```